# Can I allow only TCP connections from inside my network, using iptables on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, ip

Currently, I'm allowing all TCP connections to port `80` on my :

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I'd like to allow all TCP connections to port `5432`, but only from my local network. Is there a way to do that, using iptables?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS server 64bit, but if the answer works the same for most flavors of Linux, let me know and I can update the question title upon your answer.

Comment: If you read the first reason on the down vote tooltip you' 'll understand fully why someone downvoted your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the man page for iptables explains the -s option in detail:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Assuming that your local network is 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. BTW, if I already include `-A INPUT -j REJECT` and `-A FORWARD -j REJECT` at the bottom of my rules, do I still need the second line, due to any specific nature of using the `-s` flag?

Comment: No, I just included that as I didn't know what the rest of your rules look like. Depending on the complexity of your rules, it's good to include that anyway; for example if further in your rules you add something like `-A InPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT` to accept from that source, they also have access to http even though they're not included in the original http rule. That may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks. That's really interesting. The way the rules are interpreted reminds me a bit of CSS.

Comment: You're welcome; just remember that every target (except LOG) is a 'terminating' rule (so no further rules are processed for that packet), and rules are processed in a 'first match' pattern.